# ArrayCollection Call to a member function setValue() on null

Tags: doctrine, zend-framework3

I'm writing an application using Zend Framework 3. To manage database I decided to use Doctrine.

I have a weird issue with Doctrine. I have set up the following structure:

```
namespace Hotels\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as orm;

/**
* @orm\Entity
* @orm\Table(name="hotels")
*/

class Hotels
{

    /**
    * @orm\Id
    * @orm\Column(type="integer")
    * @orm\GeneratedValue
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * One hotel has many features. This is the inverse side.
    * @var ArrayCollection
    * @orm\OneToMany(targetEntity="Photos", mappedBy="hotels")
    * @orm\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="hotel_id")
    */
    private $photos;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->photos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getPhotos()
    {
        return $this->photos;
    }

    public function setPhotos($photos)
    {
        $this->photos = $photos;
    }

    /** @orm\Column(type="string", name="name") */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
    * @param mixed $name
    */
    public function setName($name)
    {
       $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {       
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
    * @param mixed $id
    */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

And:

```
namespace Hotels\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as orm;

/**
 * @orm\Entity
 * @orm\Table(name="photos")
 */

class Photos
{

    /**
     * @orm\Id
     * @orm\Column(type="integer")
     * @orm\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @orm\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Hotels", inversedBy="photos")
     * @orm\JoinColumn(name="hotel_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $hotel_id;

    /**
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function getHotelId()
    {
        return $this->hotel_id;
    }

    /**
    * @param mixed $hotel_id
    */
    public function setHotelId($hotel_id)
    {
        $this->hotel_id = $hotel_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

}
```

In the controller:

```
$hotel = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Hotels\Entity\Hotels')->find(1);

foreach ($hotel->getPhotos() as $photo) {
    echo $photo->getId() . "\n\n";
 }
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setValue() on null in /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php
```

Does anybody know why this error occurs and how I can fix it? Is something wrong with my mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is mistake in class Hotels code, you have written "hotels" instead of "hotel_id", i have corrected the code, as below:

```
/**
* One hotel has many features. This is the inverse side.
* @var ArrayCollection
* @orm\OneToMany(targetEntity="Photos", mappedBy="hotel_id")
* @orm\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="hotel_id")
*/
private $photos;
```